# converting android application written in android studio to windows phone app using visual studio 2015

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010

How can I convert android application written in android studio to windows phone app using visual studio 2015.What is the process for doing this?As I do not know window application development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know windows application, you can try to write your application with cordova in javascript. You can then decline your application with different plateforms :  Android, IOS, Windows ... for more info see [cordova getting started](https://cordova.apache.org)